# Don't need help solving this problem, just need some info. A push in the right direction would be nice.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> Find $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}$ given that$$\sqrt{3x^7+y^2}=\sin^2y+100xy.$$

Should I start off by squaring both sides to get rid of the radical on the left? And then start the derivative process? Thank you.

This is what I have so far:

Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$:
$$\begin{align}\frac{21x^6+2y\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}}{2(3x^7+y^2)^{1/2}} &= 2\sin(y) \cos(y) \cdot \displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx} +100\left(y+x\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\end{align}$$ I think I had made the left side $1/2$ to get rid of the root and forgot to apply it to the right side of the equation. –

I'm at $$3x^7+y^2=(\sin^2y+100xy)^2$$ then I think I would start from left to right until they are all in their derivative form?

Comment: That would be helpful, My first attempt was awful.

F' [(sqrt  3x^7+y^2) = sin^2 y+100xy]  is

[21x^6+2y(dy/dx)]/2(3x^7+y^2)^1/2] = 2sin(y) (cos(y) * dy/dx) +100(y+x(dy/dx)

I think I had made the left side 1/2 to get rid of the root and forgot to apply it to the right side of the equation.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I understand. This is not a homework problem, it's out of the book and I wanted to try it, but I'm am getting a little put-off. Haven't been doing calculus for long, maybe my mental math marathon is not up to par yet.

I wasn't too sure on how to this problem, I think I will try and square both sides and go from there.

Comment: @TangentJay I understand but this site has certain quality standards in place for a reason. None of the quality standards require you to be good at calculus. Please see this post for a [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial to get up to speed with formatting equations as well as [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1) on quality standards. Using MathJax and adhering to the QS's not only helps the MSE but will also help your questions get more attention.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent ahh I see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference I will have to read more and edit my typeset.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Understood.

Comment: (+1) on updated question.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson and TangentJay We should probably delete all comments that are unnecessary now, the comments section is pretty clogged up with our messages :)

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Will do

Answer (score 1):

If we square both sides, then we could continue like this.

$$3x^7+y^2=(\sin^2y+100xy)^2.$$
Let's first differentiate the left hand side with respect to $x$. We get
$$21x^6+2y\frac{dy}{dx}.$$ Now let's concentrate on the harder right hand side of the equation. If we were facing something like $[f(x)]^n$ and we differentiated with respect to $x$, that'd result in $n[f(x)]^{n-1}f'(x)$ by the chain rule. Our case is similar:
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^2y+100xy)^2=2(\sin^2y+100xy)\times \frac{d}{dx}(\sin^2y+100xy)\end{align}.$$
Can you finish it from there?

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Got ya, was going to ask where is the dx/dx from, then I remembered. I can.  Thanks. I'll post back after a few hours of this or maybe less.

Comment: @TangentJay No problem. What do you mean by $dx/dx$? Did you mean $d/dx$?

Comment: I have a question. If I wanted to go the route 1/2 the sqrt, will I have to apply the 1/2 to the right side of the equation like I would do if I applied a square?

Comment: @TangentJay I'm not certain exactly what you mean by 'applying it to the right side of the equation'. You already have a square root, so there is no need to apply another square root to both sides of that's what you mean.

Comment: got ya. In other words, I'm just changing the root to 1/2 on the left side, there is no reason to apply 1/2 to the right equation?

Comment: @TangentJay When you say 'changing the root to $1/2$' do you mean 'rewriting the expression as $(...)^{1/2}$?

Comment: yes, sorry. sqrt=1/2. wasn't too sure if I had to apply they 1/2 to the right side since I changed the root on the left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126757/discussion-between-a-level-student-and-tangentjay).